# Windows service properties - log on

Tags: c++, windows, service

so i was following this tutorial http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948

and i was having problems starting the service in the Service Management Console. I was getting the error message 'windows cannot start the service on local computer error 5 access is denied'

but i found that in the properties of the service i'm trying to start if i go to Log On tab and click Local System account instead of this account it works. 
I just want to know what actually happened here? and does it affect the service in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the account that is running the service. This may have a lot of implications most importantly involving permissions. It is always important from security standpoint to limit the permissions a service has.

Also a user needs to have some permissions to be able to run a service(for instance `Log on as a service`). These can be set in `Local Security Policy`->`User Rights Assignment`(this may vary depending on the windows you are running on). The user you try to run the service with seems not to have enough permissions to run your service. Try to investigate why is that.